# Proving that $0.999\ldots=1$ using the supremum axiom

Tags: inequality, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

> Use the supremum axiom to show that $0.999\ldots=1$.
>
> **Hints:** Consider the set $C=\{0.9, 0.99, 0.999, \ldots\}$.
>
> Discuss if $C$ is upper bound, and find the supremum(s) of $C$.
>
> We know that every number with decimal expansion $x=0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ is such that $0\leq x \leq 1$.
>
> What would happen if $0.999\ldots < 1$?

**My attempt:**

Clearly, $0.999\ldots=\operatorname{sup}{(C)}$ since $0.999\ldots=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}9\cdot10^{-i}$ has a $n+1$-th positive term while $\sum_{i=1}^{n}9\cdot10^{-i}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ doesn't, so $c \leq 0.999\ldots, \forall c \in C$. We know that $0.999\ldots \leq 1$, so all we need to do is show that $1=\operatorname{sup}{(C)}$. I thought about showing there is no $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $0.999\ldots < k < 1$, but I got stuck here.

**My question:**

How do I prove this with just elementary set theory? I don't want an answer based on arithmetic or analysis, since that's not how this question was meant to be solved. I would also like to know if showing $1=\operatorname{sup}{(C)}$ is the right path and if so how to proceed.

**My research:**

First, I asked my colleagues, but nobody I talked to got this question in the exam right. I tried to contact the professor but he did not respond. Online, I've found [this thread](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/supremum-proof-of-999-1.516629/) but it did not get anywhere. I've wondered about this question for months so help would be really appreciated.

Comment: There are two things you have to show:  1) $\sup C$ exists.  (It does because $C$ is bounded above).  2) That $\sup C = 1$.  And to show 2) the easiest way is to show that if $a > 1$ then $a$ can not be $\sup C$ and that if $b < 1$ then $b$ can not be either.  THen as $\sup C$ must be *something*, it is $1$.

Comment: Are you able to use that if $x<y$ you have that $x<\frac{x+y}{2}<y$?  What would the average of $0.9999\dots$ and $1$ look like?

Comment: If there were such a $k$, how would $1 - k$ compare to $1-c$ for each $c\in C$?

Comment: Note every $x \in C$ we have $x$ is *strictly* less than $1$ so $C$ is bounded above by $1$.  So $\sup C \le 1$.  Now all you have to do is prove if $b <1$ then there is an $x \in C$ so that $b > x$.  .... Then you are completely done.  (Do you follow the logic and see why that prove $\sup C =1$?  Understanding that logic is actually more important than doing the proof.)

Comment: Consider if $x \in C$ (*not* that $x = \sup C$) then$x =0.9999.....9$.  Then $1-x= 0.0000000.....1$.  Now $\sup C \ge x$ so $1-\sup C\le 0.000000......1$.  It there any number that is less or equal to all possible $0.00000.....1$ no matter how many $0$s it contains.

Comment: If such a $k$ does exist then it has a decimal expansion too which must differ from $0.999...$ at some digit. However this digit must be strictly less than $9$ since it is the largest possible digit. This implies that $k < 0.999.... < k$, a contradiction.

Comment: @fleablood I get $a>1$ because we have $0.999\ldots \leq 1$, so it can't be any number bigger than $1$. $b <1$ is a little trickier, but by your last comment, $0.999\ldots$ is not in $C$? If so I think I can solve this.

Comment: I just meant you were not supposed to confuse my $x =0.99999....9$ with $\sup C$.  I wanted to make it clear that I *wasn't* talking about $0.9999.....$ but a specific $0.9999....9$.  I wasn't meaning to imply $0.99999...... \not \in C$..... But since you brought it up......Is it?  What if it were?  That would mean $C$ has a maximum element?  Does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would happen if 0.999…<1?

Then that would mean $1-0.9999.... > 0$.

The real question is why is that a problem?

Well let $1-0.9999999 =h > 0$.

Well, as $0.9999....$ is an upper bound then every $0.\underbrace{9999.....9}_{n\ nines}\in C$ si so that $0.99999....9 \le 0.9999..... < 1$

So $1 - 0.9999.....9= 0.00000.....1=\frac 1{10^n} \ge 1-0.99999...... = h > 0$.

So $\frac 1{10^n} \ge h > 0$ no matter how big $n$ is.

Is that problem?

That means that $\frac 1h \le 10^n$ no matter how large $n$ is.

Is that a problem?

Let $M = \frac 1h$ is a valid number as $h$ is a valid positive number.  And $M$ is larger than any possible $10^n$.  *Every* possible $10^n$.  Is that possible? Is there a number that is bigger than any possible $10^n$.

.... Now's the time for you to pipe in "No, that'd be ridiculous".

So we can not have $0.99999...... = \sup C < 1$.

So $0.99999.... = \sup C \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of a fan of using decimals to establish fundamental real analysis facts like this. I prefer the existence of properties of decimal expansions be developed over a real analysis course. So, this answer will assume some things about decimal expansions that you may or may not have developed in your course.

A decimal expansion of a number $0 \le x < 1$ (which we assume exists, even if it may not be unique) must have a $0$ in the units digit, i.e. its most significant digit is in the $10^{-1}$ digit. Otherwise, if the units digit is any other digit $1 \le d \le 9$, then $x \ge d \ge 1$, as $x \ge 0$. Therefore, it must take the form
$$x = 0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots$$
where $d_1,d_2,d_3, \ldots$ are digits.

Now, increasing these digits (individually) increases the number. With this in mind, we have
$$x = 0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots \le 0.999\ldots,$$
by maximising every digit. This shows that, for all $0 \le x < 1$, we have
$$x \le 0.999\ldots \le 1,$$
where the final inequality is from the result you explicitly stated. But, $[0, 1)$ has the supremum $1$, and since $0.999\ldots$ is an upper bound of $[0, 1)$, we must also have
$$1 \le 0.999\ldots$$
Consequently,
$$1 = 0.999\ldots$$
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n=9\sum_{k=1}^n 10^{-k}$

Then $x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{9}{10^{n+1}}>0$. So the sequence is increasing.

$x_n=(10-1)\sum_{k=1}^n10^{-k}=\sum_{k=1}^n 10^{-(k-1)}-\sum_{k=1}^n10^{-k}=1+\frac{1}{9}x_{n-1}-\frac{1}{9}x_n=1-\frac{1}{10^n}$

So $x_n=1-\frac{1}{10^n}$.

The set of $x_n$'s is non-empty and bounded above by $1$. So by the Least Upper Bound Property, the sequence has a least upper bound.

$\forall \epsilon>0$ and $1-\epsilon<x_n<1$, we have $1-\epsilon<1-\frac{1}{10^n}\implies \frac{1}{\epsilon}<10^n$

We want to find an $N$ so that $n>N\implies \frac{1}{\epsilon}<10^n$.

If $1\ge1/\epsilon$, then $N=0$. Otherwise $1<1/\epsilon$. Let $A=\{n \in N|10^n <\frac{1}{\epsilon} \}$. So $A$ is non-empty and bounded above, so it has a least upper bound.  The least upper bound of a subset of the integers is an element of that subset. So we are guaranteed our $N$.

None of our $x_n$ exceed $1$. For any amount below one, however small, we can find an $x_n$ between that number and 1. It follows that $\sup \ \{x_n\}=1$.